# Injecting data into running IISExpress from SpecFlow

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bdd, iis-express, specflow

I'm new to the ASP.NET MVC 5 world and SpecFlow.  I'm trying to put together a simple example for learning purposes.  I've a ASP.NET MVC project in one assembly and a SpecFlow definition in another.  I'm trying to avoid having a database in the setup since I'm trying to keep this lightweight.  What I'd like to do is have an in-memory collection of data objects on the MVC server that I could manipulate from the SpecFlow definitions.  I.e. I want to have a flow like this:

(1) In SpecFlow I say something like

```
Given I have the following account data
  | Id  |  Balance | 
  | abc |   123    |
```

(2) Then I'd like the SpecFlow binding to inject a new Account object into the in-memory collection that running on the IISExpress process.

(3) Finally I'd like in SpecFlow to require

```
Then when I view the account balance of 'abc' 
in the web browser I am shown a balance of '123'
```

... the binding would then run WatiN to get IE to open the correct URL and parse the result.

What I'm missing is a way of injecting that data into the running IISExpress.  I can solve the problem by hard coding some config in the MVC application, but that isn't the dynamic testing solution I'm seeking.  Any advice gratefully received!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I know this is just a learning experience but I'm going to consider if this were a real system, how would you get it into a production stable code. This way you get the chance to learn more too.*

Unfortunately there is no silver bullet that is going to give you a solution to this. In fact what you are going to need is probably a bit more complicated than it first looks.

You will need,

1. An ASP.Net MVC server that delivers your public interface, (given you are using WaitiN I'll assume its a web site). This is the bit that you already have
2. A way of configuring and starting that ASP.Net MVC server so that it runs with your alternate data store. I've seen these triggered by hostnames, environment variables or startup arguments. All have problems in the long run, so just pick whatever suits to start with and re-visit when its a problem.
3. Another interface (possibly just an API and there's an excuse to learn to develop a JSON API in ASP.Net MVC) to handle the non-production operations of ensuring that your data store has the correct state in it. This could be something finely grained that lets you set the accounts and balances (which will mean lots of calls in the tests to get the data into it's required state), or something much more coarse (i.e. a single call that restores it to its "known" state).
4. A way of separating the non-production operations so that they are not available in your final production instance. You gave an example of accounts with balances, just imagine the problems if ever somebody found out they could set their balance to their desired value? Personally I would find some way of "composing" your system so this code didn't even ship into the production domain, but if security is less important then you could simply find a way of securing it.
5. Want to run your tests in parallel as you get more of them and they take longer to run? Have you thought of a way of separating the parallel streams? Maybe each test gets its own account? Maybe you want to run a separate WebServer for each test?

Now I apologise but I'm going to make you question your decisions so far. Above we have all the problems with testing everything front-to-back. It can be used in *Acceptance testing*, or as *Regression testing* but it really isn't very helpful in learning how to do these things. SpecFlow works best when you are thinking about the business processes. So do you **need** your tests to talk about web browsers? (Have a quick read of [Whose domain is it anyway?](http://dannorth.net/2011/01/31/whose-domain-is-it-anyway/))

What if instead you wrote

```
Then the account balance of 'abc' should be '123'
```

Now you have abstracted away the UI completely, this is [Subcutaneous testing](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/SubcutaneousTest.html). This would allow you to avoid the need to run your tests in a webserver, which would give you far easier ways of injecting the fake data store.

You could also write

```
When I click on 'Check Balance' 
Then it should call the 'CheckBalanceCommand'
```

This would let you test the UI tier only, and you could replace the Command layer with a *Mock*-ed layer that avoid all the data store setup.

In fact, you might even want to consider a testing architecture such as 
 - UI -> Commands
 - Commands -> Business Logic
 - Commands -> Data storage

Or you might want to just try the whole lot up front for some big ole tests? :-)

Comment: Thanks AlSki for the **very** comprehensive response.  All valid points which I'll take on board.  For my question in-the-small, the point I'm taking away is that I'll need, "Another interface...[to] ensure that your data store has the correct state in it".  I think I'll just knuckle down to getting that done.

Answer (score 0):

This is overly complicated for the sake of removing a database. What you really need to do is install a database locally and configure your web application to use that for your tests.